# Mod rewrite with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a mod rewrite script to work, but for some reason I cannot seem to get things functioning properly.  I know that mod_rewrite is working, because if I run the following test it redirects correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oranges.html$ apples.html
```

However, if I try and push all queries to an index file or something to process using php then it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .? index.php [L]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a database table with two columns, one with an ID and the other with a rewrite URL.  So what I mean by this is:

```
ID | URL
16 | nice-url-1
17 | nice-url-2
```

So the actual URL is /index.php?id=16, but I want there to be a table lookup and there to be a redirect to /nice-url-1.  Now I would have thought I would go with the second rewrite conditions, but the problem is it just does not redirect.

I am running Centos 6 with Apache 2.2.15, so I am wondering if {REQUEST_FILENAME} is just not supported.  I did try adding DOCUMENT_ROOT, but that made absolutely no difference.

Any help most appreciated.

Comment: That `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` block you've probably seen elsewhere is just a dated detour around using `FallBackResource`.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is called URL slugs. Research more on them.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an other element to your rule, to actually pass the whole url, `QSA`. This will append the existing query string to the url.

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

I also normally use the single `^` to match any url possible.